# AMD: unable to write to IOMMU while booting from debian live persistent usb

Tags: boot, memory, live-usb, amd

Hardware information:

```
System Model    NBLK-WAX9X (Notebook Honor MagicBook 15 (53010WKM))
Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, 2100 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS utility: InsydeH20 Setup Utility
```

Available options (are all about to either enable or disable the option) in the BIOS menu:
Virtualization technology, USB Port enable, HDD Device enable, PXE Device enable, Audio enable, WLAN enable, Bluetooth enable, Fingerprint enable, Keep setup values after Bios update enable, other Wakeup technology enable

```
USB live kernel installed:
https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.6.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.6.0-amd64-xfce+nonfree.iso
```

Now I have made live *persistent* usb with debian via `mkusb`: [mkusb/persistent method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent). I have been using the live usb for years on laptops with intel processor (there was no problem). So when I tried for the first time boot to this laptop with amd-based processor, I got an error:

```
AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter
```

After looking up other answers, they mostly suggest to turn IOMMU off. For example here: [AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU coun / Problem loading X.509 certificate -65][2], where they suggest to edit `/etc/default/grub` file and then invoke `update-grub`. But since that command requires to determine the boot device, and since my device (the live usb) was created by the `mkusb` utility, I have no idea what file the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"` to add to (I do not have `/etc/default/grub` config file). I do not have full understanding of the `mkusb` method described in the link above, but I can see the file-tree created by it:

```
$lsblk
loop0          7:0    0   2.3G  1 loop /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
sda            8:0    1  58.4G  0 disk 
├─sda2         8:2    1   977K  0 part 
├─sda3         8:3    1 244.1M  0 part 
├─sda4         8:4    1   2.7G  0 part /usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda4
└─sda5         8:5    1    16G  0 part /usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda5
```

where the `/usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda4` mount point should have folders with the grub config files:

```
$tree -L 3 /usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda4
/usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda4
├── boot
│   └── grub
│       ├── efi.img
│       ├── font.pf2
│       ├── grub.cfg
│       ├── loopback.cfg
│       └── x86_64-efi
├── d-i
│   ├── gtk
│   │   ├── initrd.gz
│   │   └── vmlinuz
│   ├── initrd.gz
│   └── vmlinuz
├── dists
│   └── buster
│       ├── main
│       └── Release
├── EFI
│   ├── boot
│   │   ├── bootx64.efi
│   │   └── grubx64.efi
│   └── debian
│       └── grub.cfg
├── firmware
...
```

So what file should I edit in order to boot properly to this laptop with AMD processor?

[2]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827591/amd-vi-unable-to-read-write-to-iommu-coun-problem-loading-x-509-certificate![enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827591/amd-vi-unable-to-read-write-to-iommu-coun-problem-loading-x-509-certificate!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzns2.jpg)

EDIT:
after editting in grub menu with `iommu=pt` I got another error (may non be visible in the picture)

`EXT4-fs error (device sda5): ext4_lookup: 1595: Inode #31598: comm mysqld: deleted inode referenced: 794`

Comment: Are you getting a GRUB menu when you boot off this device?

Comment: Yes, I am getting grub as first as I boot (that is normal behaviour since the grub loader is installed in the usb - as mentioned in the post - I was using it with intel-based laptops and there was no problem. So first 1) I get grub menu, 2) I select `*Debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-xfce+nonfree.iso - persistent live` option, It tries to load, but then it cannot communicate with IOMMU (and thus getting the error), but I do not know why

Comment: Try adding the `iommu=pt` to the end of the command line in the GRUB menu. Hit `e` to edit it.

Comment: See update above. Now after editing `iommu=pt`, ext4 is deleting inode (sda5 is the usb device name), but why? This does not make sense

Comment: My previous Gigabyte threw all kinds of errors if I didn't add `iommu=pt` to any live-USB I tried to boot. What about `iommu=soft` - give that a try.

Comment: Nope, still the same error. I have even try to put the command as very first, and very last statement (before or after  of `linux vmlinuz` and `initrd img` calls), but to no avail. So is my hardware incompatible with the live-kernel? Due to trying to communicate with IOMMU unit? Does my hardware even has this unit? Why is this problem only with AMD processor, and with Intel one (as I had in my previous laptop), there was no such problem? (I am not unfortunately big hardware specialist, so I have a little knowledge about it, but I know for sure it is caused because of processor changed).

Comment: The only thing I can think of to do is delve into your BIOS settings and see if you've missed anything. I have no way to test your environment.

Comment: The bios does not offer much option (Have already tried). The bios is `insydeh20 setup utility` and it has not tab for system configuration. Every option are in the same page (option like volume priority, security or "advanced"). The advanced option are for enabling/disabling some kinds of technology (like virtualization, USB port, HDD devices etc. -> I will add to hardware specification in post), But I have no direct way to manipulate with the hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115207/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-milanhrabos).