# empty screen after booting from live persistent usb

Tags: boot, memory, live-usb, amd

From my previous post [AMD: unable to write to IOMMU while booting from debian live persistent usb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614910/amd-unable-to-write-to-iommu-while-booting-from-debian-live-persistent-usb?noredirect=1#comment1149915_614910), I have tried to boot to recovery mode to see the kernel output while booting.

And while there seems to be no error (no "failed" message from kernel log), after presumably successful boot, I am left with black screen and blinking cursor.

Now I am not quite sure if it was really successful (because I see no GUI), but since there is no error, I have no idea what went wrong.

How can I determine then what went wrong, and thus I see no GUI? What happened?

EDIT:
full .mp4 format:
[video](https://streamable.com/hk8lm9)

EDIT2:
I could log in and see the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file, output here:
[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://streamable.com/uz77ej)

What it basically says at the end is:
`(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all buffer devices`
`Unable to connect to X server: Connection refused`

So I can see all my files, `/home` partition unchanged, all documents are here, but I cannot to switch to GUI tty by `Ctrl+alt+F7` because, I have error with framebuffer mode. How can I solve this?

EDIT 3:
I continue with another question here:
[cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615263/cannot-run-in-framebuffer-mode-please-specify-busids)

Comment: Add `init=/bin/bash` to the grub parameters, the system will boot to a console, maybe from there you can start some debugging.

Comment: The GIF is impossible to read.

Comment: @OskarSkog unfortunately. But I have to get between the limit of 2MiB per picture. So the quality is very low.

Comment: @OskarSkog see edit. I have added link to mp4 format with full quality. There it is possible to watch

Comment: Can you switch to tty1 (ctrl+alt+F1), log in and run `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: @OskarSkog thanks, I did log in, but still I cannot log to GUI tty with `ctrl+alt+F7`. From the log there is framebuffer mode error. See edits. Can I configure some files to define the busIDs for buffer device?