# cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs

Tags: boot, live-usb, x-server, framebuffer

from my previous question [empty screen after booting from live persistent usb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615080/empty-screen-after-booting-from-live-persistent-usb?noredirect=1#comment1150102_615080), I am able after boot to access all files and folders, but the X-server is unable to load (so I get only to tty1). From the previous question I was able to get to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and took a photo of it :

[image: /var/log/Xorg.0.log]

Now I have to somehow specify "busIDs for all framebuffer devices" (as from the file error). So how can I do that? What config file should I edit? I get the very same error from `startx` (the fatal error of unable to run framebuffer mode). How to connect to X-server?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem and solved it by installing a more recent kernel from backports. You can create a new file containing the line `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for enabling backports in `apt` if you are using Debian Buster. The `contrib` and `non-free` components will be useful if you also need to install the WiFi drivers. After that you need to install the most recent `linux-image*` package for the correct CPU architecture and reboot your system. In my case it was the `linux-image-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64` package.

For checking whether your graphics drivers are installed you can run `lshw -c display`. If the device is not correctly recognized by the kernel, it will be marked as "UNCLAIMED".

Also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420682/451521) answer.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: make sure the version for your kernel and the version for the headers match.

---

I was happily using my linux (debian with xfce) when suddenly it just restarted, but it couldn't boot, it couldn't even find the grub configuration. I didn't know what happened. So I got a clonezilla liveCD and restored grub. Disk was fine, memory was fine. After that, I was able to boot ok, but I wouldn't get a GUI. I tried manually starting X and got the same error, `Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs`. I checked `lshw -c display` as mentioned by Antonio and it was saying "UNCLAIMED". I found that very odd. Everything was working fine, why suddenly I don't have the drivers for the display? I had them before... so I checked more logs. In the boot log, I had this message:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
See 'systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service' for details.
```

When I searched for that, I found that maybe the kernel was not loading the video drivers. I checked the boot log further back and found:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details.
```

I tried running this command, and found that the system was indeed not loading the nvidia modules. I searched for that and found that my `/dev` didn't have any nvidia files. I tried following Antonio's suggestion above, I added `buster-backports` to my `sources.list`, ran a `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` first... nothing happened, but it did give me a message that `linux-headers-4.19.0-14-XXX` was not being used and it wasn't needed. At first, I didn't pay attention to that, I thought it was just left-over unnecessary header packages. But I noticed that Antonio mentioned the linux image `5.9`, and my linux image was `4.19`. Since the difference was so big, I decided to first run a `apt-get dist-upgrade` to see what would happen.... and that's when the magic happened. That command installed the new `linux-headers-4.19.0-17-XXX`, which matched the linux kernel that I was using, the version of which I hadn't even payed attention to. After a reboot, my X was working again. So what was preventing my nvidia drivers from working and my X from starting was a mismatch between the kernel and the headers.
The problem being that I didn't update the kernel, the system did that automatically, and did a poor job at it :(

So the lesson for today is: disable all automatic updates, manually update your stuff and make sure the update is successful before you can reboot. (just kidding... or am I?)

Comment: I think you had a similar problem as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299415/update-linux-headers-when-kernel-is-updated) question. On Debian 10 instead of only installing a specific version of the kernel headers you can also install the `linux-headers-amd64` or a similiar package depending on your architecture for having the headers updated automatically.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I don't think that's the problem. When I run `apt list --installed | grep -i header` I can see `linux-headers-amd64/stable,now 4.19+105+deb10u12 amd64 [installed]` which seems to be what you mentioned. Besides, when I ran the `apt-get dist-upgrade`, the header automatically updated (meaning, I didn't manually update it). I'm pretty sure the autoupdate is the one that messed things up, by installing other stuff first; then something caused a reboot before the update was complete, and put my system in an inconsistent state. :(

Answer (score 1):

Just recovered from the same error so wanted to share the solution

I reinstalled Linux firmware, kernel and headers. What did help was the last one as it also enabled Nvidia module

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. To solve it, I upgraded my linux kernel to the latest. This issue is most likely related to the linux kernel you have installed.

```
[    15.694] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.694] (EE) 
**Fatal server error:
[    15.694] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices**
[    15.694] (EE) 
[    15.694] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    15.694] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    15.694] (EE) 
[    15.695] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```